# What is the Drupal 6 equivalent or alternative to hook_node_load?

Tags: 6, nodes

In Drupal 7, there exists the function hook_node_load. Does anyone know how I can hook into a node being loaded from the database in Drupal 6? If not, can you suggest an alternative hook? I am simply trying to get my custom module to load my javascript file upon the user visiting a particular node page. Thanks.

Comment: I've found that hook_nodeapi fits my use case: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that hook_nodeapi fits my use case: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6